# Direct Hive Queries Doesn't appear in HiveServer2 WebUI

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, webui, hiveserver2

I need to know, why Direct Hive Queries Doesn't appear in HiveServer2 WebUI?

[Follow a GIF to explain my doubt.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCOck.gif)

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but `beeline` keeps an open session , and the Hive cli is deprecated, and does not. It might not show the "closed queries" until the session ends

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer , thanks about your help.

Yeah, but even I end the Hive Cli session, the HiverServer 2 WebUI doesn't show the Queries that I did in Hive Cli Session.

I need to caption this Queries in WebUI, running directly on Hive Cli.

Comment: Like I said, that's deprecated (as the terminal tells you). So is the Cloudera sandbox, but that's a different matter. The Hive cli doesn't use the same connection properties/protocol as a proper hiveserver2 jdbc client like beeline, so accurately tracking queries won't be possible with it. One option is to replace the hive binary command with an alias to beeline